# While uploading the app on app store(itunes) getting the following error`

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5, ios-provisioning, itunes-store

[image]

I am trying to upload my app on itunes evrything is correct certificate, provisioning etc,  but every time I got this error.

Comment: What did you find out when doing research on the error you received?

Comment: I found some solution for similar type of error but not for the exaclty same key ie. com.apple.developer.networking.vpn.api

Comment: I noticed there were a number of other SO questions for the entitlement error (with other keys) that seemed to have similar answers. Did you try any of those?

Comment: yes I have tried 1 was to check the provsioning and refresh the listed provisionings in the xcode but nothing worked and another solution was running the app on iphone not for upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using VPN apis in your app, but your app ID does not have appropriate entitlements.

It is possible you have an entitlement service that you have not correctly configured in your app ID setup on apple's developer site.  Log into your developer account, go to "Certificates, Identifiers, and Provisioning".  Go to your app ID for the app you are submitting, and click on it.  You will notice under Application Services, there are is a service called "VPN Configuration & Control".  Try turning that on, and re-creating your provisioning profile for the app ID.  Then re-build the app.

It is also possible that you are using internal VPN APIs outside of what is allowed in the "VPN Configuration & Control" service, in which case Apple will continue to reject your upload for using APIs reserved for internal or special use (as in the case with the Cisco AnyConnect app).